# webpack, why react-dom increase size in about 150kb?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

we are working in a webpack, react, redux, ... based project. Trying to minimize as much as possible the final bundled file we found that `react-dom` increases the file size in about 150kb.

We have made some tests creating a dummy app that only includes `react` and the final minimized+optimized size is about 20kb (something reasonable taking into account the minimized version of react.
Next if we also include `react-dom` the final bundled size is about 170kb.

Is really `react-dom` as big? Anybody has some experiences to share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me, it's 44kB (without `react-dom`) versus 226kB (with `react-dom`). The `react-dom` package isn't that big, but the main part of its code is actually located inside the `react` package itself (not the `react` _module_, though).

Comment: Thanks, then I see sizes are normal. On the other side, try adding ```new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }
  })```and check if you reduce de 226kb to something lower.

Comment: Good point, that reduces it to 22k (without) and 152k (with).